# How can i use ejs and css style?

Tags: css, node.js, ejs

I have a page ,

**server.js**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.get('/link', (req, res) => {
   res.render('link' , {
      title: 'this is title'
    }
)};
```

**views/link.ejs**

```
 <% include partials/header %>
 <%= title %>
 <p class="myStyle">this is sample text in center</p>
```

**views/partials/header.ejs**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

**public/css/style.css**

```
.myStyle {
   text-align: center";
 }
```

so, this page works fine if i put url like this -> `localhost:8080/link`

but if i put url like this -> `localhost:8080/link/` than the style is mismatch.

what can i do for this ??

Answer (score 1):

How do you have your files directory structured? I imagine the issue is there, as adding the '/' at the end of the URL like you have in your second URL is telling the browser to look in the sub-directory 'link', that is a step further 'down' inside your file structure.

Comment: okay i figured out
i just add '/' before the href link
/css/style.css
thanks it worked.